# Android - Are there any ad networks with custom sized mobile ads?

Tags: android, ads

I've been implementing ads in an android application, but I wanted to make one that was 200x100px. All I could find were banner ads and none of them could be a custom size, or at least close to the desired size. Are there any mobile ad networks that would provide this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out

https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=ww-ww-et-asfe_&utm_source=aso&answer=185668

But I am not sure if we can have small adds for high density screens. Which means it is compulsory to keep add width and height to wrap content and the content automatically either takes complete width or is not shown